# Couldn't get the required correct output

Tags: c, hamiltonian-cycle, hamiltonian-path

I'm trying to solve the Hamiltonial cycle and path problem using backtracking method whether a source vertex is given for the input graph. When all the vertex are visited in that input graph, then the path will be displayed. Using backtracking approach, I want to get all the hamiltonaial path or cycle for the input graph.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int m=0;
int ans[5];

void Hamilton(int G[5][5], int visited[5], int n, int f){
    if(m == 5-1){
        for(int i=0;i<f;i++)
            printf("%d ",ans[i]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        visited[n] = n;
        m++;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            if(G[n][i] == 1){
                if(visited[i] == -1){
                     n = i;
                     ans[f++] = i;
                     Hamilton(G, visited, n, f);
                }           
            }
        }
        visited[n] = -1;
        m--;
        return;
    }
}

void main(){
    int G[5][5] = {
        {0,1,1,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,1},
        {1,0,0,1,0},
        {0,1,1,0,1},
        {0,1,0,1,0}
    };
    int n = 0;
    int visited[5] = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    ans[0] = 0;
    Hamilton(G, visited, n, 1);
}
```

But in the output, nothing is showing in the output screen

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: What an attractive, clear and descriptive title..... Please understand that "wrong output" is the second most boring title, occuring about ten times a day. Just surpassed by "please do my homework for me".

Comment: A) Under what conditions does this print? B) Where are those conditions set? C) Are you *sure* you're setting the right conditions? D) Why are you using global variables?

Comment: Blank screen, huh? Did you try something like `printf("Start.\n");` as the first thing in your program? That would be a debugging trick to notice when something outside of your algorithm blocks your program from outputting anything. Please try a HelloWorld, to test.

Comment: have some discriptive names for variables. not only will it help you in debugging, it will also help others looking into your code

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  Did you read what the `dsa` tag represents?

Comment: Don't use global variables. More often than not, they make your programs undebuggable, especially recursive ones.

Comment: The code increments m from 0 to 3 and then decrements it back to 0.  It never gets to 4.

Comment: Please explain how `G` and `visited` are supposed to work; it is not really obvious. I assume that is an adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 0):

One error is that by `n = i;` you overwrite the original vertex `n`, and due to this the resetting `visited[n] = -1;` later doesn't work. A second error is that `f` is only incremented and never decremented on backtracking. We can correct those two errors by changing

```
                     n = i;
                     ans[f++] = i;
                     Hamilton(G, visited, n, f);
```

to

```
                     ans[f] = i;
                     Hamilton(G, visited, i, f+1);
```

- still a remaining problem in the general case (not with cycle graphs as the given G) is that this `Hamilton` function only finds paths that start at vertex 0.